# "Unable to dequeue a cell with identifier" Error

Tags: swift, swift3

I have created a TableViewController, not inside a ViewController, it is it's own controller, as one of my views inside my app, it is written in Swift 3. I keep getting a "Unable to dequeue a cell with identifier" error. From what I have found it is from the Identifier not being set inside the Storyboard, but I have set it to that value. The cell settings are: style: Basic Identifier: EntryCell. The table view that is is part of is set to 'Dynamic Prototypes' and Prototype Cells: 1

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //self.tableView.register(UITableView.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "EntryCell")
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "EntryCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath)
    let storyEntry: CKRecord = entries[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = storyEntry.value(forKey: "title") as? String
    return cell
}
```

I have tried taking the cell out and creating it on the fly but that doesn't work as well.

Any idea would be great appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Make sure the reuse identifier for the cell is set to `EntryCell` (no quotes) on the SB.  One of the most common issues I've seen in circumstances like this is someone copies their identifier from their code and pastes it in the identifier field in storyboard, but leaves the quotes. It's something that's hard for your eye to catch. I'm not sure that's your problem, but it's worth checking.

Comment: I checked that and that wasn't the issue. I created a whole new TableViewController and created a new view in my app and added the exact same set up with this cell and it worked.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to solve this problem is to create a .xib file containing your cell. Then, instead of loading the cell using:

`let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "EntryCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath)`

Load the cell using:

`let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("myXIBFileName", owner: nil, options: nil)!.first as! myCellClass`